# Appended information disappears and search function runs when reset button is pressed

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, append

When i press the reset form button, the appended information appears briefly, before being replaced by the search results. Onchange and onclick events are bound to the the form HTML tags.

```
 <script>
  function resetform(){
  setTimeout(function(){
  $('#appendresults2').empty();
   $('#appendresults2').append('<div class="noresults"><h1>Please enter your       query</h1></div>');



 }, 50);

return;
}
</script>

<div id="appendresults2"><div class="noresults"></div></div>


<button class="btn btn-default" type="reset" onclick="return resetform();">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

HTML

```
<div id="appendresults2"><div class="noresults"></div></div>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="reset" onclick="resetform()" id="reset" >Reset</button>
```

Jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#reset").click(function(){

 setTimeout(function(){
  $('#appendresults2').empty();
   $('#appendresults2').append('<div class="noresults"><h1>Please enter your       query</h1></div>');
 }, 50);
  });
});

</script>
```

See fiddle here....http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBGUL834B4MW

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Though I neglected to mention that onchange and onclick events are bound to the the HTML tags, so this solution gives the same results.